# How to run function on click with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently am making a quiz in which specific answers load images, based on the answer one picked. So I grabbed the 'input' tags and now I have them to be manipulated with. However, I have no idea on how to run my function, while putting in the inputs[i] as a parameter.

Considering that each inputs[i] is different, my idea of:

```
$('input').click(getImages)
```

Failed. So I do not know where else to go with that.

```
// run getImages
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++ )
    {
        inputs[i].onclick = getImages(inputs[i]);
    }
})



function getImages(x){
    // variables
    var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    var images = {
        '1.1' : 'images/aggressive.jpg',
        '1.2' : 'images/compassionate.jpg',
        '1.3' : 'images/timid.jpg',
        '2.1' : 'images/clean.jpg',
        '2.2' : 'images/moderate.jpg',
        '2.3' : '',
    }

    if (x.name === '1')
    {
        p1.src = images[x.value];
    }
    if (x.name === '2')
    {
        p2.src = images[x.value];
    }
}
```

A solution that I felt would work would be grabbing the inputs by individual ID, but I don't know how many inputs I will have in the end, and I don't want my code to work specifically for that.

Comment: you are passing html `input` element to `getimages`. you can get the clicked element using jquery also. See my answer below and you can also cutback on setting up images array everytime someone clicks an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var p1, p2, images;
// run getImages
$(document).ready(function(){
    setup();
    $('input').click(function(){
        //if you want to pass jquery object uncomment following line
        //getImages($(this));
        //this passes html object 
        getImages(this);
    });
})

/*you don't need to do this every time*/
function setup(){
    // variables
    p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    images = {
        '1.1' : 'images/aggressive.jpg',
        '1.2' : 'images/compassionate.jpg',
        '1.3' : 'images/timid.jpg',
        '2.1' : 'images/clean.jpg',
        '2.2' : 'images/moderate.jpg',
        '2.3' : '',
    }
}

function getImages(x){
    if (x.name === '1')
    {
        p1.src = images[x.value];
    }
    if (x.name === '2')
    {
        p2.src = images[x.value];
    }
}
```

<strike>You can try `index()` function of jQuery.</strike>

```
$("button#test").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

You can check if this will work for you at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/Pd97N/)

Comment: thanks @bfavaretto updated the answer to user `this` in place of `$(this)[0]`

Comment: Great! This worked! Thank you so much for the help. I don't know how I didn't try that.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    getImages(parameters);
});
```

Or something like:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var x = 1;
    // Or to get the params from the current element, use something like this:
    x = $(this).attr("src");
    getImages(x);
});
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to pass in arbitrary parameters but rather know /which/ image was clicked. Perhaps you should update to use `$(this)` or `this` to show how those can be used from getImages?

Answer (score 3):

I think; looking at what you are doing, all you may need is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(getImages); //Bind the click handler
});

 var images = {
        '1.1' : 'images/aggressive.jpg',
        '1.2' : 'images/compassionate.jpg',
        '1.3' : 'images/timid.jpg',
        '2.1' : 'images/clean.jpg',
        '2.2' : 'images/moderate.jpg',
        '2.3' : '',
    }


function getImages(e){
     var img = 'p' + this.name; //Get the respective image id based on the input's name
     document.getElementById(img).src=images[this.value]; //Grab the image src from the list and set the value.
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsZF8/)

With your statement `inputs[i].onclick = getImages(inputs[i]);` issue is that you are binding click handler with the result of the function `getImages(argument)` (**Instead of function reference**) which returns nothing hence `undefined` will be set as the click handler for these inputs and image will be set to the respective src of the last respective input(name) due to the loop that you have.